# Why my word count using combineByKey in Spark is emitting two times the sum of the values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying the `combineByKey` from Spark to count words. I am not sure, but I guess the functions of merge and combiner could be the same because the count operation can be the same on the combiner and on the reducer. This would not happen if I was taking the average.
How can I implement this word count using the same function for the merge and the combine?

Other thing is why my result is showing two times the value that I am counting? How can I implement the `combineByKey` to show only the key and the sum of the values only once?

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.{HashPartitioner, SparkConf}

import scala.collection.mutable.Queue

object TestStreamCombineByKey {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("QueueStreamWordCount")
      .setMaster("local[4]")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))

    // Create a DStream that will connect to hostname:port, like localhost:9999
    val rddQueue = new Queue[RDD[String]]()
    val lines = ssc.queueStream(rddQueue)

    val wordCounts = lines
      .flatMap(_.split(" "))
      .map(word => (word, 1))
      .combineByKey(
        (v) => (v, 1), //createCombiner
        (acc: (Int, Int), v) => (acc._1 + v, acc._2 + 1), //mergeValue
        (acc1: (Int, Int), acc2: (Int, Int)) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2), // mergeCombiners
        new HashPartitioner(3)
      )

    wordCounts.print()

    ssc.start() // Start the computation

    // Create and push some RDDs into the queue
    val thread = new Thread("pool data source") {
      override def run() {
        while (true) {
          rddQueue.synchronized {
            rddQueue += ssc.sparkContext.makeRDD(List("to be or not to be , that is the question , or what would be the question ?"))
          }
          Thread.sleep(100)
        }
      }
    }
    thread.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination() // Wait for the computation to terminate
  }
}
```

my current output. Why is it showing two times the sum of the values?

```
(or,(2,2))
(would,(1,1))
(?,(1,1))
(the,(2,2))
(not,(1,1))
(is,(1,1))
(that,(1,1))
(be,(3,3))
(what,(1,1))
(question,(2,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what you are doing in your `combineByKey` block, instead of initializing into tuple `(v,1)` just keep it as is, i.e  `v => v`,

You should change your code like this to get value only once,

```
val wordCounts = lines
      .flatMap(_.split(" "))
      .map(word => (word, 1))
      .combineByKey(
        (v:Int) => v, //createCombiner
        (acc: Int, v:Int) => acc + v, //mergeValue
        (acc1: Int, acc2: Int) => acc1 + acc2, // mergeCombiners
        new HashPartitioner(3)
      )
```